# Passing variable with include tag php

Tags: php, variables, include

I am attempting to pass a variable to a different php file, my code to get the variable is this,

```
<?php  
    global $changeDate;
    $changeDate = $_POST['editdate'];
    $results = "SELECT title, DATE(start) FROM rota WHERE DATE(start) = '$changeDate' ";
    $workingUser = mysql_query($results);   
    include 'phpfunctions/holddate.php';
?>
```

holddate.php is this,

```
<?php
    $holdingdate = 0; 
    $holdingdate = $changeDate;
?>
```

on execution I get an error saying `$changeDate` is an undefined variable in holddate.php, where is this going wrong? This includes the `global` setting recomended but still recieve same error.

Comment: Why are you creating the variable `$holdingdate` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt have to use global attribute or sesions.
Try turning errors on and see if you get any errors returned.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

From the DOCS

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

I would try to stay away from creating global variables unless its absolutely necessary.  Also since you already tried tht and it does not work there is another problem besides the variable scope.

Comment: "**I get an error** saying $changeDate is an **undefined variable** in holddate.php" said in the question, if you ddn't notice it

Comment: @YourCommonSense  Kinda sad you have nothing better to do than try to make yourself feel better by rude and unhelpful comments.  Grow up cool guy

Comment: @YourCommonSense because he gets a NOTICE returned does not mean he has error reporting on.  It just means E_NOTICE is set.  Maybe take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

```
<?php
    global $changeDate;
    $changeDate = $_POST['editdate'];
    $results = "SELECT title, DATE(start) FROM rota WHERE DATE(start) = '$changeDate' ";
    $workingUser = mysql_query($results);   
    include 'phpfunctions/holddate.php';
?>
```

Comment: I have created the global variable but still returning the same error

Comment: Did you set up the global variable on the top of the file ?

Comment: @user2967211 If you're still around, show us what your form looks like.